# ¿Por que se generan dos encriptaciones iguales en la base de datos utilizando sha1?

Tags: php, mysql, sha1

estoy creando un restablecimiento de contraseña, pero al momento de actualizar la contraseña o restablecerla con un encriptación sha1, me crear siempre la misma encriptación y al loguearme con la nueva contraseña o la vieja contraseña no me deja.

código del update para restablecer la contraseña

```
<?php

include("Conexion.php");

$objConexion = Conectarse();
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($_POST['nuevopass'] ===  $_POST['confirmarpass']) {
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($objConexion, $_GET['nuevopass']);
        $password_nuevo =  sha1($password);
        
        $correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($objConexion, $_POST['correo']);
        $token = mysqli_real_escape_string($objConexion, $_POST['token']);


        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_login_registro SET Contrasena= '$password_nuevo', Token = '$token'
         WHERE Correo = '$correo'";
        $resultado = $objConexion->query($sql) or die($objConexion->error);

        if ($resultado > 0) {

            echo "<script>
            alert('Tu contraseña ha sido actualizada!');
            window.location = 'login.html';
            </script>";

        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>
alert('La dos contraseñas que ingresaste no coinciden');
window.location = 'login.html';
</script>";

    }
}
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comentario no-respuesta: SHA1 es considerado inseguro para cifrar contraseñas. Busca implementaciones recomendadas en PHP, que seguro las hay. La [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) así lo indica. (Hay que leer la documentación siempre!)

Comment: Ahora sí, comentario-respuesta: para qué validas en el IF que `$_POST['nuevopass']` no esté vacío si después escapas `$_GET['nuevopass']`?? Posiblemente todas tus contraseñas son iguales y son el hash generado por una cadena vacía :P :P

Comment: En efecto, usando http://www.sha1-online.com/ generé un hash de una cadena vacía y, adivina qué: `Result for sha1:  da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709`

Comment: vale muchas gracias lo revisare